# Independent ordered queues for job that is process exactly same way

Tags: queue, message-queue, amqp

I am looking for a queuing tool to help me process jobs in order. I will use an example of user joining a website to help convey the problem, in real life they are more dull jobs which can each take up to 1 minute, there are several thousand users.

**user1** - Registration  -> Process Payment -> Upload photos -> Resize photos

**user2** - Reset password -> Log in -> Upload photos -> Resize photos

The above jobs all need to be processed in order for that user. i.e. you can not process payment before the registration has finished. Each of these jobs is processed in the same way (fire of a http request to an external service).

If user 1 registration takes a long time their is no reason for user 2 to wait for his password reset. If I had multiple workers on a single queue the next job to be popped off could be anything so a users tasks may be processed in the wrong order.

At the moment I have a hacked together system which does this using a redis list but its not ideal and needs improvement. If there is an off the shelf tool or pattern which does this it would be great. I thought I could potentially programataclly create a new queue on rabbitmq for each user but felt it wasn't designed for that so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use [amqp message groups](http://qpid.apache.org/books/0.20/AMQP-Messaging-Broker-CPP-Book/html/Using-message-groups.html) which are supported by some clients, I ended on using  [fairy](https://github.com/baoshan/fairy) as I am using nodejs already.